# Color Indicator in the Status Bar?

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to make my status bar menu have a background color [green/yellow/red] depending on a given status. I think the Level Indicator Cell should be helpful, but how can it be put in the status bar?

A relevant blog article:
http://dacc.exaptic.com/2009/02/color-status-bar-in-cocoa-with-nsindicator/

Answer (score 4):

Create the `NSLevelIndicator` (a subclass of `NSView`), and use it to `setView:` on your `NSStatusItem`.