# NSLevelIndicator with text on It?

Tags: cocoa

How can I add text on top of a NSLevelIndicator? [the NSLevelIndicator is in my statusbar, if that matters]

Answer (score 3):

The best way to add text to your `NSLevelIndicator` user interface is by adding a separate Label `NSTextField`.  The `NSLevelIndicator` control does not have a title or other text associated with it.

From within Interface Builder, just grab a Label and drag it to your window above or beside the NSLevelIndicator.

Comment: Since this is within a status item, the questioner probably means z-on-top-of, not y-on-top-of. That is, text in the foreground, level indicator in the background. That can be problematic: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW16

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to [the correct answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695070/color-indicator-in-the-status-bar/1695075#1695075), if you want to use an NSLevelIndicator as a background *and* draw text on top of it, you're better off creating a custom view that owns and uses an NSLevelIndicator*Cell* for the background drawing.

You might also consider drawing the background yourself; e.g., fill with your choice of green/yellow/red, and then draw a white gradient on top of it. This is more appropriate if you're not really indicating a level with your level indicator.

Also, don't forget to test your application with [Sim Daltonism](http://michelf.com/projects/sim-daltonism/), to make sure that the text is still readable to color-blind users.